# Matlab Multidimensional matrices: Most efficient way to perform addition on one of the dimensions

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have got a three-dimensional matrix

```
sigma = zeros(3, 3, 1000)
```

and a single matrix

```
result = [0.5 0.5 0.5; 0.2 0.2 0.2; 0.1 0.1 0.1]
```

My question would be: What is the most effective way to add my matrix 'result' to every single matrix along the third dimension of 'sigma'?

Currently I am looping over all 1000 matrices and add them one by one. Is there a Matlab-optimized way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
bsxfun(@plus, sigma, result)
```

It automatically replicates the smaller matrix along its singleton dimension to match the other matrix.

Comment: Interestingly, this does not seem to be faster than looping over all individual matrices.

Comment: MATLAB has improved JIT acceleration in the last few releases, so I won't be surprised if looping would actually be slightly _faster_ for small matrices. For larger matrices though, I believe you would see the difference `bsxfun`.

Answer (score 2):

sigma + repmat(result,[1,1,1000])

In general, calls which pass functions (although more efficient than looping) aren't as well optimized under the hood as those involving only native code.

Comment: I think that `bsxfun` is well optimized for the built-in functions listed in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html). It is `repmat` which tends to be slower and less memory-efficient. Try to benchmark your solution against a for-loop and `bsxfun`, you'll see that it's almost an order of magnitude slower...

Comment: I don't have MATLAB, but in Octave, sigma+repmat... is about three times as fast as bsxfun (in that when I change 1000 to 100000, bsxfun takes about 6 seconds on my laptop while +repmat takes about 2 seconds)

Comment: It good to know, and you definitely earn +1 for the effort. This question is tagged [tag:matlab] though...

Comment: Okay, in the future when I answer a Matlab question on stackoverflow, I'll add the caveat that I'm actually an octave user and running times may vary.  I didn't know bsxfun was so well optimized for particular functions in Matlab.

Comment: In general, it's always worth testing your solution on the platform in question :-)